# Android Accessability RecyclerView reading "in list X items"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, talkback

So I am using RecyclerView for a page. When the user goes from outside the recyclerview to inside the recyclerview, talkback reads "in list X items" (x is number of items in list) at the end. Is there any way to stop it from doing this? One easy fix is marking it as not important for accessibility in XML but that means that accessibility does not scroll to all the items properly when part of the list is off screen.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand adding collection information is done in RecyclerView's
method

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager :: onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo
```

method

try adding an accessibility delegate and resetting this information

```
recyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(object : RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate(recyclerView) {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
        host: View,
        info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
    ) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
        
        info.setCollectionInfo(null)
    }
})
```